# Set a wxImage to a specific wxColor

Tags: wxwidgets

Is there a way to set every Pixel of a wxImage to a specific wxColour?
I am looking for a simpler way then to iterate over the pixels.
Maybe there's some built in fucntionality in wxImage already?

Answer (score 1):

You can use method [wxImage::SetRGB](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_image.html#a17f90246727d089675e7f44a414280d1):

`wxImage::setRGB(const wxRect &rect, unsigned char red, unsigned char green, unsigned char blue)`

which sets the colour of the pixels within the given rectangle. But this method does not affect pixels alpha value (if the image has alpha channel).

On the other hand, you can convert your image to wxBitmap and fill it with desired colour using [wxDC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html#ad0139f6542f619244b80d4db7f685f86) (or just create empty bitmap, fill with the colour and then convert to wxImage). Here is the example:

```
wxBitmap bitmap(my_wxImage_instance);
wxMemoryDC memdc;
memdc.SelectObject(b);
memdc.SetBackground(*wxGREEN_BRUSH);
memdc.Clear();    //fills the entire bitmap with green colour
memdc.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);
my_wxImage_instance = wxBitmap(bitmap);    //optionally
```

[wxMemoryDC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_memory_d_c.html) description.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the (good) answer by @nnatarr, you can also use [wxImage::Clear()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_image.html#a2aa815c34284d6a85971e1ff8a2cc74c) to set the image to any grey colour, including black or white.